# How to find a pattern between two non-alphanumeric character using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I am very new to python regex. i am not able to get a clear idea about how to search for " * " in a sentence , since * is used as a keyword in regex i am getting confused.
my question is , i have a file in which :

```
*CHI:   <that guy was> [//] that bunny was going to [: gonna] take that
    balloon !
%mor:   pro:dem|that n|bunny aux|be&PAST&13S part|go-PRESP
    part|go-PRESP~inf|to v|take pro:dem|that n|balloon !
```

So in this i have to retrieve the sentence that is between "*CHI :" and "%mor"

my desired output should be

```
<that guy was> [//] that bunny was going to [: gonna] take that
        balloon !
```

Comment: It isn't clear what your input cases might be or what the regex pattern you're after is. Will `*CHI:` or `%mor:` always follow that format, i.e., asterisk/percent followed by 3 alpha followed by colon followed by 4 spaces at beginning of line? Please clarify.

Comment: @ggorlen Yes the pattern will always be the same throughout my input file. I just have to fetch the sentence that is in between "CHI:  " and "%mor"

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `re.DOTALL` flag to make `.` match newlines; there's no need for lookarounds:

```
import re

s = '''*CHI:   <that guy was> [//] that bunny was going to [: gonna] take that
    balloon !
%mor:   pro:dem|that n|bunny aux|be&PAST&13S part|go-PRESP
    part|go-PRESP~inf|to v|take pro:dem|that n|balloon !
'''

print(re.search(r'\*CHI:   (.+)\n%mor:', s, re.DOTALL)[1])
```

Output:

```
<that guy was> [//] that bunny was going to [: gonna] take that
    balloon !
```

[Try it out](https://repl.it/repls/OilyClutteredMicroscope)

Answer (score 0):

**You can put * inside []. Inside the character class [] the metachars like *

are stripped of the special meaning.**

```
['*']
```

with re.search

```
t = """*CHI:   <that guy was> [//] that bunny was going to [: gonna] take that
    balloon !
%mor:   pro:dem|that n|bunny aux|be&PAST&13S part|go-PRESP
    part|go-PRESP~inf|to v|take pro:dem|that n|balloon !
 """

mo = re.search(r'[*]CHI:\s+(.*)\s+%mor:', t, re.S)

mo.group(1)

'<that guy was> [//] that bunny was going to [: gonna] take that\n    balloon !'
```

With re.findall

```
re.findall(r'[*]CHI:\s+(.*)\s+%', t,re.S)  

['<that guy was> [//] that bunny was going to [: gonna] take that\n    balloon !']
```

Comment: @LetzerWilleI tried something like this but i am not able to get my desired output can you help me with this ?  
 **re.findall("(?s)\*CHI :([^*CHI]+)\%", line)**

Comment: @LetzerWilleI can u please answer to my answer posted

Comment: your answer shows unclosed character class error. can u please edit with updated cde

Comment: @MaTHwoG. Please look at the updated answer. cut and paste of code in comment did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the '*' character:

```
re.findall(r'(?<=\*CHI:)[\s\S]*(?=%mor:)', s)
```

The positive lookbehind '?<=' and positive lookahead '?=' will trim your start and end terms. 
[\s\S] will take care of newline characters.